# 2010 Designer Workflow - add 1 condition and it won't publish

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a very large list (column-wise) (no actual documents yet other than 2-3 testing ones) in SharePoint 2010 where I have customized the form using the InfoPath designer.

I am trying to create a simple workflow where it emails certain people at certain times.  I got it to the point where it would email a Person or Group field, and CC another Person or Group field.  Problem was, when the CC field was empty, the workflow would fail.

So I tried to add a simple condition whereas when the CC field was blank, it sent one email, and if it was not blank, it sends another email.  As soon as I add that condition - whether it is directly on the field, or on a string variable set to the contents of that field - I can no longer publish.

Error is:

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow.  The workflow files were saved but cannot be run.
>   Unexpected error on server associating the workflow

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share ULS logs? Also refer to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2557533) link, maybe it will help.

Comment: Please read this post maybe you can help:
   http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/115652/33569

Answer (score 1):

I receive the same error on SharePoint Designer 2010 when creating multiple conditions with an email workflow.

If I add 3 email messages, the workflow does not publish. Basically, my workflow sends an email message to the appropriate distribution group based on a drop-down selection picked from a form.

When I delete the body of the email message, the workflow publishes. For more info on error, check out this support message from Microsoft at [SharePoint Designer 2010 Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run. Unexpected error on server associating the workflow.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2557533)

Re-registering the workflow service may resolve your issue.

Here is more info: [Solution: Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run.](http://sp2013.pro/2013/04/solution-errors-were-found-when-compiling-the-workflow-the-workflow-files-were-saved-but-cannot-be-run-cannot-set-unknown-member/)